# Evaluate a triple integral, got two different answers

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate 
$$\int\int\int_D x^2+y^2+z^2 dV$$ 
where $D$ is the solid lying inside the sphere of radius $1$ centered at $(0,0,1)$ and inside (i.e above) the cone $x^2+y^2=3z^2$.

First, I tried to evaluate it using the spherical coordinate: $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta\int_{0}^{\pi/3}d\phi\int_{0}^{2\cos\phi}r^2\sin\phi dr\cdot r^2 = \frac{21\pi}{10}$$

And then I evaluated it using the cylindrical coordinate:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta\int_{0}^{\sqrt 3/2}dr\int_{\sqrt{r^2/3}}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}+1}rdz(r^2+z^2) = \frac{107\pi}{60}$$

So which is correct?

Comment: for cylindrical coordinate, I forgot to add the other part!!!!

Answer (score 1):

for cylindrical coordinate,
I forgot to add the other part of the volume 
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta\int_{\sqrt3/2}^{1}dr\int_{-\sqrt{1-r^2}+1}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}+1}rdz(r^2+z^2)$$